# Ho do I validate entire column of YYYYMMDD entries, and check whether they are valid dates or not in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have few columns which contain date data in yyyymmdd format. I want to validate if the entries are valid or not. How do i do that?

Comment: What are the conditions for "valid or not" ?

Comment: Note that the marked duplicate contains some remarkably bad answers, only one upvoted one, and that one contains a clear compile error. I'm casting a reopen vote because it shouldn't have been possible to mark this as a duplicate, since that answer shouldn't have been upvoted and marking as a duplicate requires upvotes on at least one answer.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, post a data example. Anyways, if your data is just `yyyymmdd`, then probably something like `=DATE(LEFT(A1;4);MID(A1;5;2);RIGHT(A1;2))` should be able to validate your data.

Answer (score 1):

Select the whole column and run Text-to-Columns, Fixed width, Date: YMD, Finish. Anything that can be converted to a true date will be converted to a true date.

```
with Selection
    .TextToColumns Destination:=.cells(1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                   FieldInfo:=Array(0, xlYMDFormat)
end with
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should validate a date in `yyyymmdd` format that Excel understands as a date.

Note that there is a special case made for 29-Feb-1900 in the 1900 date system.
1900 was NOT a leap year.  But Excel recognizes that as a valid date, allegedly to create compatibility with Lotus 1-2-3 which was doing the same thing.

```
Option Explicit
Function validExcelDate(num As Long) As Boolean
    Dim Y As Long, M As Long, D As Long
    Dim leapYr As Boolean
    Dim dt1904 As Boolean

dt1904 = ThisWorkbook.Date1904

'Would also be valid year if test passed
If num < IIf(dt1904, 19040101, 19000101) _
    Or num > 99991231 Then Exit Function

'special case
If num = 19000229 Then
    validExcelDate = True
    Exit Function
End If

D = num Mod 100
M = Int((num Mod 10000) / 100)
Y = Int(num / 10000)

'valid month
If M < 1 Or M > 12 Then Exit Function

'valid day
If D < 1 Then Exit Function
leapYr = LY(Y)

Select Case M
    Case 4, 6, 9, 11
        If D > 30 Then Exit Function
    Case 2
        If D > 29 Then Exit Function
        If leapYr = False And D > 28 Then Exit Function
    Case Else
        If D > 31 Then Exit Function
End Select

validExcelDate = True
End Function

Private Function LY(yr As Long) As Boolean
    If yr / 4 = Int(yr / 4) And _
        Not (yr / 100 = Int(yr / 100)) Then _
        LY = True
    If yr / 400 = Int(yr / 400) Then LY = True
End Function
```

Comment: Hey i am a beginner, Can you please elaborate how to apply this function to multiple columns for example, say G,K and V.  Thanks!

Comment: This UDF has no column specific references. Perhaps a book about VBA programming would be of use:  eg **Excel VBA Programming For Dummies** to get you up to speed.  I've not read that book, but Walkenbach seems to be able to explain things clearly in other things I've read from him.